# Does heating a jar lid significantly expand the metal?

Tags: everyday-life, metals

> *The heat from hot water expands the air inside the jar relieving the amount of negative pressure inside the jar. Hot water may additionally help to loosen any sticky material inside the jar lid from the canning process. Enough heat to expand the metal lid would be difficult to handle.*
>
> [Stan](https://stackexchange.com/users/3216333/stan), in [lifehacks.SE comment](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/141/tricks-for-opening-very-tight-jars#comment17485_147)

1. Does changing the temperature of a typical metal lid from, say 60° F to 110° F change the metal significantly enough to ease opening the lid?
2. Does heating the air inside the jar have a greater impact than the effect on the metal itself?
3. Are there other effects of heat on the metal besides expansion which are significant to opening the jar?

Answer (score 0):

1. Not really, but you don't need much.
2. Yes, in case sticking is the main issue.
3. Sugar syrup or honey softens when heated

Answer (score 0):

The coefficient of thermal expansion for aluminum is $24 \cdot 10^{-6} /K$.  So raising the temperature by 50 degrees Fahrenheit ~ 28 degrees Celsius/Kelvin means it would expand by less than one thousandth.  However, the difference needed is actually very small, on the order of a tenth of millimeters spread over several centimeters.  So (1) should help

(2) actually hurts the process due to increased air pressure making it stick more.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your response to question (2)? The jar is starting at negative pressure, so increasing this to atmospheric pressure would equalize the pressure and seem to help.